# Rexec pip installation fails in Python 3.4

Tags: python

Command:

```
pip install rexec
```

Error traceback:

```
Downloading/unpacking rexec
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement rexec
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for rexec
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\JSR-PC\pip\pip.log
```

Comment: Are you using Python 3 ?

Comment: yes. i am using Python 3.4

Comment: (My bad, written in title) rexec does not exist in Python 3. It has been deprecated since version 2.6 and removed in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

The rexec module does not exist in Python 3. It has been deprecated since version 2.6 and removed in Python 3.

Source  : https://docs.python.org/2/library/rexec.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in answer from iFlo rexec module was removed from Python 3 and although you can find it in Python 2, it was deprecated. However if you want to create resource restricted environment you might want to try [pypy](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/) to create your own interpreter with constrained use of resources.